# how to auto create pdf using highchart graphs

Tags: php, jquery, yii, highcharts, html2pdf

I am using yii framework 1.14 with php on centos 5. I have designed a view that contains 4 graphs created using highcharts. i want to export this page to pdf from my controller/action method. 
The following is what I have so far. the html gets produced fine but when i try to export to pdf i only get the headers in the view and no graphs.

**controller/action**

```
if(isset($_GET['report'])){

            $graphs = 4;
            $arr = array();
            $where = array(
                    array("PROJCODE"=>array("Woking","Cairo"),"MC"=>array("MC")),
                    array("PROJCODE"=>array("Houston","Cairo"),"MC"=>array("MC")),
                    array("PROJCODE"=>array("Jakarta"),"MC"=>array("MC")),
                    array("MC"=>array("P")),
                    );
            $title = array(
                    array("Woking & Cairo"),
                    array("Houston & Cairo"),
                    array("Jakarta"),
                    array(""),
                    );

            for ($i = 0; $i < $graphs; $i++) {  
                $model=new ViewWebprojectreport('weeklystatus');
                $model->unsetAttributes();          
                $dataProvider = $model->weeklystatus($where[$i] );
                $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = $model->count();
                //print_r($dataProvider);
                $blank = array();
                foreach ($dataProvider->getData() as $data) {
                    $blank[] = $data;
                }

                $count = 0;
                $command = array();

                foreach ($dataProvider->getData() as $data) {
                    $count++;
                    $command[$count]["PROJECT"] = $data->PROJECT;
                    $command[$count]["StartDATE"] = $data-> StartDATE;
                    $command[$count]["ProjectEndDate"] = $data-> ProjectEndDate;
                    $command[$count]["PERCENT"] = $data-> PERCENT;
                    $command[$count]["MC"] = $data-> MC;
                    $command[$count]["MC"] = $data->ActualEndDate;

                    $count++;
                }
                $totalprojects = $count;

                $cat = array();
                $totalLength = array();
                $schedule = array();
                $complete = array();
                $planned = array();

                $totalprojects = count($command);
                $scrollcount = 0;
                if(count($command)>20)
                    $scrollcount = count($command) - 10; // set scrollbar depending on records returned

                foreach ($command as $key => $value) {
                    $cat[] = $value['PROJECT'];
                    $date_from = (strtotime($value['StartDATE']) )*1000;
                    $date_to = (strtotime($value['ProjectEndDate']) + 1*86400)*1000;


                    if($value['MC'] == -1)
                        $totalLength[] = array("low"=>$date_from,"high"=>$date_to, "color"=>"#2f7ed8");
                    elseif($value['MC'] == 0)
                    $totalLength[] = array("low"=>$date_from,"high"=>$date_to, "color"=>"#0d233a");
                    else
                        $totalLength[] = array($date_from,$date_to);

                    $today = time();
                    $startdate = strtotime($value['StartDATE']);
                    $enddate = strtotime($value['ProjectEndDate']);


                    if( $value['ProjectEndDate'] == ""){
                        $enddate = $startdate;
                    }

                    $diff_total = $enddate - $startdate;
                    $diff_today = $today - $startdate;

                    $schedule[] = array( $date_from,  $today*1000 );

                    // work out number of days completed by percent complete of project
                    $percentage_to_get = round((float)$value['PERCENT'],2);
                    $percentage_of_days =  ((int)$value['PERCENT'] == 0)? 0 : floor($diff_total/100*$percentage_to_get);
                    $percentComplete = (($startdate + $percentage_of_days)+ 1*86400)*1000;

                    $complete[] = (float) $value['PERCENT'];
                    $planned[]=($diff_today != 0 && $diff_total != 0) ?  ( ((($today - $startdate) /  ($enddate - $startdate))*100) > 100 ) ? 100 : (($today - $startdate) /  ($enddate - $startdate))*100 :  0;

                }

                $arr[] = array('cat'=>$cat,
                        //"data"=>$totalLength,
                        "complete"=>$complete,
                        "planned"=>$planned,
                        "totalprojects"=>$count,
                        "title"=>$title[$i],
                        "key"=>$i);

                //echo $i;
                //print_r($arr);
                //echo "<br><br>";
            }
            $this->layout = 'weekly_status_graph';
            $html = $this->renderPartial('weekly_status_graph',array("arr"=>$arr),true);
            /*
            # mPDF
            $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();

            # You can easily override default constructor's params
            $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('', 'A4');

                    # render (full page)
            $mPDF1->WriteHTML($html);

                    # Load a stylesheet
                    //$stylesheet = file_get_contents(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.css') . '/main.css');
                    //$mPDF1->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);

                    # renderPartial (only 'view' of current controller)
            //$mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('index', array(), true));

            # Renders image
            //$mPDF1->WriteHTML(CHtml::image(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot.css') . '/bg.gif' ));

            # Outputs ready PDF
            $mPDF1->Output();
            */

            $pdf = $this->createPdf();
            $pdf->setOptions(array('orientation'=>'Landscape',
                    'margin-top'    => 0,
                    'margin-right'  => 10,
                    'margin-bottom' => 0,
                    'margin-left'   => 10,
            )
            );
            //$this->layout = 'pdf';


            $pdf->renderPage('weekly_status_graph',array("arr"=>$arr));
            $this->render('weekly_status_graph',array("arr"=>$arr));

            $pdf->send('w'.date('M-Y').'.pdf');
```

**view**

```
<head>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/highcharts/highstock.js"></script>

<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script> 

<script>
function redyellowgreen(x){
    //console.log($(x).parent());
    $(x).attr('fill','url(#MyGradient)');
}

function createGradient(svg,id,stops){
      var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
      var grad  = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'linearGradient');
      grad.setAttribute('id',id);
      for (var i=0;i<stops.length;i++){
        var attrs = stops[i];
        var stop = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'stop');
        for (var attr in attrs){
          if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr)) stop.setAttribute(attr,attrs[attr]);
        }
        grad.appendChild(stop);
      }

      var defs = svg.querySelector('defs') || svg.insertBefore( document.createElementNS(svgNS,'defs'), svg.firstChild );
      return defs.appendChild(grad);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Multiclient Projects</h1>
<?php foreach ($arr as $key=>$value){?>
<?php if($key==3)
    echo "<h1>Propiertary Projects</h1>";
?>
<div id="weekly_status_graph<?=$key?>" style="height:600px;width: 900px;">

    <?php $this->renderPartial('weekly_status_graph_template',$value);?>
    </div>
<?php }?>

</body>
```

**view2**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//function buildColumnGraph(data){  
    var projects_title = <? echo json_encode($title);?>;

    $('#weekly_status_graph<?=$key?>').highcharts({


    //var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart:{
            type:'column',
            //inverted:true,
            //renderTo: 'container'
        },      
        title:{
            text:projects_title
            },
        xAxis:{
            categories:<? echo json_encode($cat); ?>,
            //min: data.scroll,
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis:{
            min:0,
            max:100,
            title: {
                text: '% COMPLETE'
            },
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        tooltip:{
            formatter: function(){              
                if(this.series.name == "Actual"){
                    return "Actual POC " + this.y + "%";
                }else if(this.series.name == "Planned"){
                    return "Planned POC " + this.y + "%";
                }
            }  
        },
        legend:{
            enabled:true,
            verticalAlign:'top',
            align:'right',
            floating: true,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        series:[
                    {
                    'name':'Planned',
                    'data':<? echo json_encode($planned); ?>,
                    'color': "rgb(91,155,213)"  
                    },
                    {
                    name:'Actual',
                    data:<? echo json_encode($complete); ?>,
                    color: 'rgb(237,125,49)'    
                    }
                ]

    }); // end of columngraph      


    // create linear gradient for legend in 2 graph
    createGradient($('svg')[0],'MyGradient',[
        {offset:'3%', 'stop-color':'red'},
        {offset:'95%','stop-color':'#10f200'}
    ]);

//}
});


</script>
```

If i put  on the view and use my pdf printer to create pdf. it creates the x and y axis of the graphs but no columns.

**UPDATE**

I am trying to do the following which shoudl create the image and place in temp dir. I have set up highcharts to use local exporting server.

```
var data = "filename="+<?=$key?> + "&type=image/png&width=900px&scale=2&svg="+$("#weekly_status_graph<?=$key?>").children("div").contents("svg");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/protected/extensions/highcharts/exporting-server/php/php-batik/index.php',
        data:data,
        success : function(data) {
        }
    });
```

The jquery result i get is

```
<pre>About to transcode 1 SVG file(s)

Converting 5ea8ca9b4530955b6076e033627b1f49.svg to temp/5ea8ca9b4530955b6076e033627b1f49.png ... ... error (SVGConverter.error.while.rasterizing.file)
</pre>Error while converting SVG. 
            <h4>Debug steps</h4>
            <ol>
            <li>Copy the SVG:<br/><textarea rows=5>[object Object]</textarea></li>
            <li>Go to <a href='http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input' target='_blank'>validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input</a></li>
            <li>Paste the SVG</li>
            <li>Click More Options and select SVG 1.1 for Use Doctype</li>
            <li>Click the Check button</li>
            </ol>
```

This passes an SVG object to batik. what do i need to correct?

Comment: Export graphs as images, then put them into your view. It's the only way.

Comment: that is what i am trying to do. how can i export them without user intervention

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

Comment: is there a way i can do it using ajax query like above. the post is not transferring all the data so it does not work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed `phantomjs` in my controller, created an array and encoded it with json with output to file. Then used `phantomjs` to convert it to image. See the code below.

I am using `Yii` and have `highcharts` located in the extensions folder which contains everything I need. I had to download and place `batik` in that directory.

```
$json = json_encode(array(
                        "chart"=>array(
                            "type"=>'column',
                            "width"=>1000,
                            "height"=>350
                            ),
                        "title"=>array(
                                "text"=>$title[$i]
                                ),                          
                        "xAxis"=>array(
                            "categories"=>$cat,                         
                            "labels"=>array(
                                "rotation"=>$rotation,
                                "align"=>'left',
                                "style"=>array(
                                    "fontSize"=>'8px',
                                    "fontFamily"=>'Verdana, sans-serif',
                                    "width"=>"75px"
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        "yAxis"=>array(
                            "min"=>0,
                            "max"=>100,
                            "title"=>array(
                                "text"=>'% COMPLETE'
                            ),
                            "tickInterval"=>10
                        ),
                        "plotOptions"=>array(
                            "column"=>array(
                                "pointPadding"=> 0.2,
                                "borderWidth"=> 0
                            )
                        ),                      
                        "legend"=>array(
                            "enabled"=>true,
                            "verticalAlign"=>'middle',
                            "align"=>'right',
                            //"floating"=> true
                        ),
                        "credits"=>array(
                            "enabled"=> false
                        ),                      
                        "series"=>array(
                            array(
                                'name'=>'Planned',
                                'data'=>$planned,
                                'color'=> "rgb(91,155,213)"
                            ),
                            array(
                                "name"=>'Actual',
                                "data"=>$complete,
                                "color"=>'rgb(237,125,49)'
                            )
                        )                       
                    ));

                $file = "protected/extensions/highcharts/exporting-server/php/php-batik/temp/$i.json";
                // Write the contents back to the file
                file_put_contents($file, $json);
                // generates images to use for weekly status report
                shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/phantomjs protected/extensions/highcharts/exporting-server/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js -infile protected/extensions/highcharts/exporting-server/php/php-batik/temp/${i}.json -outfile images/$i.png -constr Chart");
```