# Different approach to generate PDF of a HTML page which contains 10 highcharts using mPDF in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts, mpdf

In a project reporting section, we have around 10 highcharts on each of our HTML pages . We have to give an option to user to download these pages as PDF. This application is running on PHP 5.4.16 and we are using codeigniter framework. For generating pdf we are using mPDF.

Current approach (How we are generating it right now)

1) When the reporting page loads the highcharts on the page, each of highcharts are pushed into  an array in SVG format with other chart detail with this code.

```
charts.push({title:chartData[key]['analytics_type'],text:key,svg:chart.getSVG()});
```

2) On the click of save as PDF, I submit this array to my controller with other required data.

3) controllers first covert each SVG chart into an image file with this code.

```
      private function svgToJpg($item) {
      $filename =  isset($_POST['filename']) ? $_POST['filename'] : 'chart';
      $width =  isset($_POST['width']) ? $_POST['width'] : 800;

      $svg=$item->svg;
      if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $svg = stripslashes($svg);
      }

      $tempName = md5(rand());
      $typeString = '-m image/jpeg';
      $ext = '.jpg';
      $outfile = TEMP_PATH.$tempName.$ext;

     if (isset($typeString)) {
        $width = "-w $width";
// generate the temporary file
        if (!file_put_contents(TEMP_PATH.$tempName.".svg", $svg)) {
            die("Couldn't create temporary file. Check that the directory permissions for
                the /temp directory are set to 777.");
        }

// do the conversion
        try {
            shell_exec("chmod 777 ".TEMP_PATH.$tempName.".svg");
            $output = shell_exec("java -jar ". BATIK_PATH ." $typeString -d $outfile $width ".TEMP_PATH.$tempName.".svg");
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die("Could not create the image. Seems like Java is not installed.");
        }

// catch error
        if (!is_file($outfile) || filesize($outfile) < 10) {
            echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
            echo "Error while converting to JPG from SVG. ";

            if (strpos($output, 'SVGConverter.error.while.rasterizing.file') !== false) {
                echo "SVG code for debugging: <hr/>";
                echo htmlentities($svg);
            }
        }
```

4) Finally, we are generating a HTML page with these images and then writing it to a PDF using  $mpdf->WriteHTML($html).

This approach is working fine but take long time to generate the PDF. May be the most time is consumed in the converting SVG to image.

Is there any other faster way to generate pdf with highchart..? I have seen the another approach of this but the link mentioned in the answer are not working:- 
[how to auto create pdf using highchart graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907904/how-to-auto-create-pdf-using-highchart-graphs)

Please suggest the way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with complicated layouts by using phantomjs, a headless browser.  It generates pdfs, as well as loads of other formats. Basically you would load your html from a php script and call phantomjs to take a screen shot and rasterize it to a pdf.